# How can I install Eclipse with Ant 1.8?

Tags: 10.04, apt, eclipse

I have previously installed eclipse on lucid with ant 1.7 with no trouble.  I need to update my ant to 1.8, but this required me to uninstall eclipse, since the "ant1.8" package isn't seen by apt-get as satisfying the eclipse package's requirement for ant >= 1.7.blah.

What do I need to do to convince apt-get that the eclipse package's ant version requirement is satisfied?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ant 1.8 (and uninstall eclipse, but not what it depends on) and download eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr2. All dependencies are already installed, two things upgraded.

Comment: That's a great workaround and I will definitely use it but my real goal is to install the eclipse package.  It's easier for me to make an image if I'm doing everything with packages, and I do not want to build an eclipse package myself.

Comment: @Jack Twilley Eclipse comes with a single directory. I think it is easy enough...

Comment: The single directory and the modification to the main menu so it comes up in Applications > Programming are pretty much it, so I might just end up doing it that way.  I do wish they'd fix the package, but I'm not holding my breath.